# Visual Studio 2019- You must have a license to use this ActiveX control

Tags: vb.net, activex, telnet

I am getting this error "You must have a license to use this ActiveX control"

You must have a license to use this ActiveX control. (System.Windows.Forms)

---

Program Location:

at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()

I converted a small project from VB6 to VB.NET, on one machine I can see my form but on another, I can't see the form in design time but the software runs fine.

Comment: That was the common way that licensing was done back in the ActiveX days.  Works just fine anywhere but putting it in design mode requires a properly installed license key.  Seems you don't have one.  You won't find one here, you need to run the vendor-provided installer and call them for support if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you are you referring to Visual studio license or the Telnet Control license?

Comment: To the ActiveX license. See whether you have `.lic` file somewhere (could also be in `\Windows\System`).